# What are *.so.*T files for?

Tags: makefile, autotools, libtool

In the log I see a line

> /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libgiomm-2.4.so.1.0.25T /mydir/glibmm-2.16.4/glibmm-2.16.4/gio/giomm/TEMP/usr/lib/libgiomm-2.4.so.1.0.25

Thats the only place where I see this T file in the build ouptut.
Who generates this file and why? Why doesn't it install .libs/libgiomm-2.4.so.1.0.25?

Comment: off topic, I think it belongs on superuser.se

Comment: I disagree; I think it *would* be OT on superuser.se. This question is about a build tool (e.g. a programming toolset) generation choice and the methodology used. Now, maybe it's just a convention for a particular library build which puts it in a "gray" area, but .. it likely doesn't belong on superusers.se ..

Comment: @pst I could see how it could go the other way as well.  I voted for superuser because it seems to be about a specific file format, irrespective of the fact that this file is used by a program.

Comment: It's not a specific file format (it would be an SO of the appropriate flavour), just a file name has an extra character at the end initially (but not at the target). I suspect it means "T"emporary, but would only venture such as an answer after looking at the particular build script (which I am not about to do) or have more experience with autotools (as I have very little).

Comment: @Woot4Moo This is not a question about filetype. Its a question about autotools/libtool.

Comment: @ghostcoder ah sorry that was me getting confused on the actual question.